# Meaning of 積み重ねる in a sentence from a book

Tags: meaning, reading-comprehension

I am reading the book 猫の客 by 平出隆 and I have problems understanding the following sentence.

> 高さの分った欅の頂点が、ある部屋の窓から見えるかどうかということになると、丘や窓の高さが測られ、想像の三角形がさらに**積み重ねられて**いくことになる。

My attempt is:

*Given the height of the zelkova, in order to determine whether we can see the zelkova from a certain window, measure the heights of the hills (where the zelkova and the window are located) and the height of the window, and (something to do with the imagined triangle).*

Further context from the book is

> 測量者の影の長さが、測量者自身の身長と同じになる瞬間に、高さを測定したい対象物の影の長さを測る。別の方法ではこうである。測定対象物の影の傍らに棒を立て、
> たがいに相似の二つの三角形を想像し、対象物の高さと棒の長さとの比が、二つの影の長さの比にひとしいことから、高さを割り出す。どちらの方法も東(ひがし)から光が来る午前中に、庭の中で行なうことのできる測量だった。これらは、ミレトスのターレスがピラミッドの高さを測量したときに用いたのではないかと推測されている方法である。その場合、ただひとつ困難があり、それは、ピラミッドの影の長さをその底部の中心から測ることであった。この困難は、隣家の欅の場合、欅の中心位置から
> 直接測定することができないことに該当するだろう。だが、今日では、精密(せいみつ)に測量された縮尺率の高い地域の地図があるから、これを併用すれば問題は解決する。
>
> 高さの分った欅の頂点(ちょうてん)が、ある部屋の窓から見えるかどうかということになると、丘や窓の高さが測られ、想像の三角形がさらに**積み重ねられて**いくこと になる。
>
> まず、丘や窓は影をつくってくれないから、次の方法を用いる。すな わち、見あげる測量者が高さを測りたい一点を指差して、その腕の水平からの 角度を測定する。この角度によって三角形の頂点の座標、各辺の長さ、方位角 を決定できるというものである。最後に目の高さを加算する。

The point is that the narrator is using a method called triangulation to determine whether he will be able to see his favourite zelkova if he moves to a new apartment.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me to be a pretty straightforward figurative use of the word. The literal meaning, as you probably know, is to pile up. And here it means something along the lines of "there will be a lot of (imagined triangles)" "a lot of (imagined triangles) will be used."

I have read the passage, and I think the gist of it is pretty clear. The author explains his recommended methods which basically all come under triangulation, as you already pointed out--relying on similarity and trigonometric calculation.

After a paragraph where he explains how using the similarity of two triangles the height of something not easily measurable can be measure, he goes on to propose a solution to another problem which he suggests needs more imagined triangles.

> 高さの分った欅の頂点が、ある部屋の窓から見えるかどうかということになると、丘や窓の高さが測られ、想像の三角形がさらに積み重ねられていくことになる。

Roughly goes like:

> If we consider the problem of determining if the top of a tree whose height is known can be seen from the window of a room, we need to use even more imagined triangles and calculate the heights of the hill and the window, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was stuck on this.